# Cannot navigate from inner stack to outer stack in react navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I have an application where I have to work with a lot of navigation using stacks and tabs.

So I have these Stacks:

```
Routes (StackNavigation)
  - Start 
  - Login
  - ProtectedRoutes (TabNavigator)
    // Depending on which type of user is logged in
    // I have to change the number of tabs that are displayed
    - Reports (StackNavigator)
      - ...More Routes
    - Payments (StackNavigator)
      - ...More Routes
    - Invoices (StackNavigator)
      - ...More Routes
    - Account  (StackNavigator)
      - AccountPage
        // The account page has a button "Logout", 
        // when clicked removes all the user data
        // and should redirect to Login screen 
        // from Routes stack (The Root Stack)
```

**The Problem:** Whenever I click on Logout button in `AccountPage`, RN throws an error saying there is no route as Login defined (which is because, we are in accounts stack and there is nothing defined as `Login` there).

Now, how can I redirect the user back to the Login Screen which is in the Root Stack i.e. `Routes` from the inner Stack i.e. `Accounts`?